# How to use svgZ with \includesvg?

Tags: graphics, svg

I am trying to load an SVGZ using \includesvg. It always looks for the SVG instead of the svgz (see error below). I know I can unzip the SVGZ to get the SVG, but I would prefer using SVGZ to keep the file size smaller.

```
There's no file `test.svg'
in folder `images/'.
```

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
        \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{images/test.svgz}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make a full minimal example, not all uses are familiar with `\includesvg` (3) are you sure `svgz` is even supported?

Comment: I don't think `svgz` files are supported. You might want to automate this by a shell escape and unzipping it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I just checked the documentation and as you both expected `svgz`is not supported :( https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf

Comment: Although it probably does not help much for vector images, you could try to save the `svg` as `pdf` (using Inkscape etc.) and see if the `pdf` compression algorithms can reduce the filesize. Otherwise you might be able to simplify the `svg` file in the program that created the file, or avoid it altogether and recreate the image in LaTeX (if it is some kind of plot or diagram, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svg` package calls Inkscape to convert a SVG file to PDF. And Inkscape can handle SVGZ files. You just need to give the option `svgextension=svgz`.

```
\documentclass[a4papaer]{article}
\usepackage{svg}
% by default graphic and text is split, so text can be set with LaTeX
% I did not want this here
\svgsetup{inkscapelatex=false}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
        \includesvg[svgextension=svgz,width=\textwidth]{example-image.svgz}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```